# Not all instructions in for loop being executed

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

The following code with line 18 commented, given this data:

```
1
3 3 1
```

yields

```
field 1 1
field 1 2
field 1 3
field 2 1
field 2 2
field 2 3
field 3 1
field 3 2
field 3 3
```

However if I leave the line as it is, it only executes the scanf(...) every second step. Where is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char field[102][102];

main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while (t--)
    {
        int r, c, n, i, j;
        scanf("%d %d %d", &r, &c, &n); // wczytanie liczby wierszy, kolumn, dni
        for (i=1; i<=r; i++) // wiersze
        {
            for (j=1; j<=c; j++) // kolumny
            {
                printf("field %d %d\n", i, j);
                scanf("%c", &field[i][j]); // line 18 here
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you scan for a character you actually send two: the letter, which gets scanf-ed, and and "hidden" '\n' which is read the next time. Just use a getch() after the scanf to read (and discard) that newline.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're trying to populate a 2D array with characters manually.

As BlackBear mentioned, you're getting a free `'\n'` character with each `scanf()` looking for character input. So that's why you're "skipping" input from the user. You can see this if you print the ASCII of the character being entered:

```
printf("field %d %d\n", i, j);
scanf("%c", &field[i][j]); // line 18 here 
printf("%d\n", field[i][j]);   // This line will print the values as they're going
                               // into the field array
```

So using this you could see something like:

```
1
2 2 1
field 1 1
10           <-- I didn't enter anything! but there's a ASCII 10 there
field 1 2
h            <-- I entered 'h', which is 
104          <-- ASCII 104 (in dec)
```

So compiring this to the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can see 10 is a newline.

Again consuming the newline (with each `scanf()`)gets rid of the problem:

```
    scanf("%d",&t);
    getchar();
    ...
    scanf("%d %d %d", &r, &c, &n); // wczytanie liczby wierszy, kolumn, dni
    getchar();
    ...
    scanf("%c", &field[i][j]); // line 18 here 
    getchar();
```

Also, just thought I'd note that your variable `n` is not used.